# kibana 4 how to change color of charts?

Tags: colors, kibana-4

I am using kibana4. My dashboard looks good. but default kibana provides green color for big portion of chart. If I want to change this color preference how can I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is very bad solution but if you want you can use it because right now kibana 4 is not providing any feature(As per my knowledge) so that we can change color of charts from any configuration.

In kibana at the path src/public/index.js following line of code is there. if you change this you can change you colors.

```
return function SeedColorUtilService() {
    return [
      '#5e87b0',
      '#57c17b',
      '#006e8a',
      '#663db8',
      '#bc52bc',
      '#9e3533',
      '#daa05d'
    ];
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In kibana 4.2 ,You can also change the color of the charts here :

```
Settings --> Advanced --> visualization:colorMapping
```

You can give the color of your choice in hex format.